# How to pass a file that changes name to another command in Bash?

Tags: linux, script, zip, wget

I frequently use wget to download tarballs and zip files from the web, then either untar then or gunzip them. I do:

```
wget google.com/somefile.zip
unzip somefile.zip
rm somefile.zip
```

Is there a way for me to automatically pass the zip file to tar or unzip WHILE wget-ting? In pseudocode:

```
wget google.com/somfile.zip && unzip
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could avoid using intermediary files and the problem would disappear

```
wget -O - http://example.com/file.zip | funzip
```

Comment: So this will work despite not giving unzip the file name of the document? If so, +1 and accepted. Nice and clean.

Comment: Yeah, note the difference between `unzip` which acts on files and `funzip` which acts on `stdin`.

Comment: @MaxMackie yes, the `-O -` means 'output to stdout'. There is no file, no document. There's just a pipe directly to `funzip` which will extract to the CWD.

Comment: I do rather like this one better than my answer. I've never run across funzip before! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
MYFILE=filename; wget google.com/${MYFILE} && unzip ${MYFILE} && rm -f ${MYFILE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers here work, and @RedGrittyBrick 's answer eliminates the temp file that you delete anyway (I'd accept his). I'll add another way.

You can do [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) on the variables you use for the URL to get the output file.

```
URL=google.com/somefile.zip
wget $URL
FILE=${URL##*/} # strip everything up to last /
unzip $FILE
rm -f $FILE
```

Comment: I think you mean "everything up to *last* /"?

Comment: @slhck good point, I changed to be last /, in both comment and code. Thanks